# Изменение переменной с помощью кнопки в PyQt5

Tags: python, button, python-3.5, pyqt5

Мне надо создать виджет в котором при нажатии на кнопку будет добавляться 1 к значению переменной и вывести его на экране

Допустим есть шкала здоровья и сытости. Каждые 4 секунды сытость убавляется. Нужно сделать кнопку которая будет добавлять +1 к значению, соответственно восполняя шкалу

Вот кусок кода и его надо добавить в код PyQt и привязать к интерфейсу

```
health = 10
satiety = 11

while True:
    time.sleep(4)
    satiety -= 1
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Если бы Qt Designer показывал код, то проблем не было бы, а так приходится работать в анаконде и я не могу найти в интернете подобный код. Может плохо искал. Если да, то покажите где или все таки скажите как вывести через PyQt5 переменную в окне и как сказать кнопке что бы она прибавляла данное значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[self.btn.clicked.connect(self.satiety_change)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784084/how-to-pass-arguments-to-functions-by-the-click-of-button-in-pyqt)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QProgressBar, QToolButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QTimer

class Window(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, satiety: int, satiety_add: int, satiety_minus: int, satiety_delay: int):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.satiety = satiety  # сытость
        self.satiety_add = satiety_add  # добавляться к значению сытость
        self.satiety_minus = satiety_minus  # убавляется от значения сытость
        self.satiety_delay = satiety_delay  # Каждые 4 секунды

        self.bar = QProgressBar(self)  # есть шкала сытости
        self.statusBar().addPermanentWidget(self.bar)

        b = QToolButton(self, text='+%s satiety' % satiety_add)   # кнопку которая будет добавлять
        b.clicked.connect(lambda: self.satiety_change(self.satiety_add))  # при нажатии будет добавляться к сытость
        self.setCentralWidget(b)

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.set_minus_satiety)

        self.satiety_change()
        self.timer.start(self.satiety_delay)

    def satiety_change(self, add=0):
        self.satiety += add
        if self.satiety > 100:
            self.satiety = 100
        elif self.satiety < 0:
            self.satiety = 0
        self.bar.setValue(self.satiety)  # соответственно восполняя шкалу

    def set_minus_satiety(self):
        self.satiety_change(add=self.satiety_minus)  # сытость убавляется
        self.timer.start(self.satiety_delay)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Q = QApplication([])
    W = Window(satiety=100, satiety_add=1, satiety_minus=-20, satiety_delay=4000)
    W.show()
    Q.exec_()
```